# The operation on .vmdk file fails in Vmware 12

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

When I run Windows 10 virtually on my Vmware Workstation 12 pro in ubuntu 16.04, after some minutes I work the below message pops up and I have to choose the 'cancel' since 'continue' and 'retry' button show this message to me again and choosing 'cancel' terminates virtual machine. 
How can I resolve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Was your system doing some disk I/O operation at the time? I have the same problem (this is Mar 2018...) but was using Win 10 as host and Ubuntu 16.04 as guest on VMWare Player 12. It almost always happen when I try to update my VM with apt-get.

I came across this post which may explain our problems:

http://itsallmacademic.com/2012/01/28/operation-on-file-vmdk-failed/

I know neither of us are running Mac, but the explanation seems valid. In short the problem is allocating too much RAM to the VM while the host cannot provide that much. I'm trying it to see if it fixes the problem or not. Hope this help...